# Regex that matches everything before an underscore

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a fair bit of RegEx knowledge, but I'm stumped by this one. I need a RegEx that matches everything *before* the last underscore, but *only* if the text after the underscore is "self", "ally" or "enemy".

So if I have input strings like this:

```
"hero_anti_infantry_melee_2_self"
"anti_infantry_ranged_2_ally"
"suppression_aoe_enemy"
"reinforce_btn_down"
"inset_energy"
"suppressed"
```

I want them to output as:

```
"hero_anti_infantry_melee_2"
"anti_infantry_ranged_2"
"suppression_aoe"
//No Match (not match because it isn't enemy, ally, or self after the underscore)
//No Match
//No Match (not underscores or enemy/ally/self
```

This is using the C# RegEx engine, and it can use any RegEx options necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a lookahead. Something like this should work:

```
new Regex(@"^.*(?=_(ally|self|enemy)$)")
```

The `(?=`...`)` means [pretty much what you wanted](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html):

> Zero-width positive lookahead. Matches at a position where the pattern inside the lookahead can be matched. Matches only the position. It does not consume any characters or expand the match. In a pattern like one(?=two)three, both two and three have to match at the position where the match of one ends.

*edit*: MSDN has [better examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) for this.

Comment: Also realised I gave the wrong examples. I'm not sure if that's effecting this or not, since this Regex doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I had a typo in the regex - `)$` instead of `$)`. I also changed it to C# syntax - and actually checked it works this time.

Comment: Works perfectly. And I think the use of a lookahead makes the most sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

This method will give you the desired result. This uses named group regex match.

```
 private static string GetStringBeforeUnderscore(string input)
 {
     string matchedValue = 
         Regex.Match(input, "(?<Group>.*)[_](self|ally|enemy)").Groups["Group"].ToString();

     return matchedValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

/(.+)_(ally|self|enemy)/

Comment: I tested it, and it looks like the pattern includes the enemy\ally\self after the underscore. I'd rather it matches up the that last underscore, but only if the letters after it are enemy\ally\self (see the first 3 examples). Also what are the slashes before and after for?

Comment: That's php/perl syntax, you will want to only examine the first capture of the match for your purposes.  (.+_)(ally|self|enemy)

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet comment to the other answer by Macy Abbey, so here it goes:

If you only want to match the word at the end you need to append a "$" at the end of the search string:

```
/(.+)_(ally|self|enemy)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string [] vars=
       new string[]{ @"data\ui\textures\generic\decorators\hero_anti_infantry_melee_2_self",
@"data\ui\textures\generic\decorators\anti_infantry_ranged_2_ally",
@"data\ui\textures\generic\decorators\suppression_aoe_enemy",
@"data\ui\textures\generic\decorators\reinforce_btn_down",
@"data\ui\textures\generic\decorators\rinset_energy",
@"data\ui\textures\generic\decorators\suppressed" };

 Regex re = new Regex("^(.*)_(ally|self|enemy)");

var xx= vars.Select(x => re.Match(x).Groups[1]);
foreach (var y in xx)
    Console.WriteLine(y.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It no doubt does work, but in this case I need simply the first match to become the result, regardless of grouping.